# Google Sheets - REGEXEXTRACT

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I've tried this for a while now and I can't find a way to extract names out of an e-mailadress format like this: "peter.johnson@mail.com". When I use the following execution:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "(.*)\.(.*)@")
```

It outputs:
"peter" "johnson" into two seperate cells.

What I really want is "peter johnson" into one cell.

This is the testsheet. Any help is appreciated.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PN2Ger6HjubU2pYuhfLiFEbFQHfNfeuVDNCDVwYN_jo/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the function JOIN by doing some extra research in how to combine two cells. Correct formula is now:

```
=JOIN(" ",REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "(.*)\.(.*)@"))
```

Which outputs: "peter johnson".

I'll leave spreadsheet shared for example.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to replace the dot and anything past the @, `=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\.|@.*"," ")`, though this leaves  a trailing space.